# Planned contrasts in mixed models

Tags: r, anova

My experiment consists of two factors, one between and one within subject. `Age` is the between-subjects factor and holds two levels: (low and high). `Time` is the within-subject factors and holds three levels: 1, 4, 5. `dv` is my dependent variable, and `id` is an identifier for each participant. I attached the data for the 6 first participants.

Using R, I ran an ANOVA that yielded significant results for both factors. I have two planned contrasts:

1. In time 1, I want to compare the two age groups (low vs high). That is, a between subject comparison.
2. In age low, I want to compare Time 1 and Time 5. That is, a within subject comparison.

Of course I could perform t-tests, yet it seems not appropriate as I can base my standard error estimate on more cells here. My question is how can I perform the above contrasts, and what are the appropriate degree of freedom?

```
structure(list(id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "5", "6", 
"7", "8", "11", "12", "13", "15", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", 
"22", "23", "24", "25", "27", "28", "29", "31", "32", "34", "35", 
"36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", 
"48", "49", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "58", "59", "60", "62", 
"63", "64", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", 
"75", "77", "79", "80", "81", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", 
"89", "90", "91", "92", "93", "94", "96", "97", "98", "99", "100", 
"101", "102", "103", "104", "105", "106", "107", "108", "109", 
"110", "111", "112", "113", "114", "115", "116", "117", "118", 
"119", "120", "121", "122", "123", "124", "125", "126", "127", 
"128", "129", "130", "132", "133", "134", "135", "136", "137", 
"138", "139", "140", "142", "143", "144", "145", "146", "147", 
"148", "149", "150", "151", "152", "153", "154", "156", "157", 
"158", "159", "160", "161", "162", "163", "165", "166", "167", 
"168", "169", "171", "172", "174", "175", "176", "177", "178", 
"179", "180", "181", "182", "183", "184", "185", "186", "187", 
"188", "189", "190", "191", "192", "193", "194", "195", "196", 
"200", "201", "202", "203", "204", "205", "206", "208", "209", 
"210", "212", "213", "214", "215", "216", "217", "218", "219", 
"220", "222", "223", "224", "226", "228", "230", "231", "232", 
"233", "234", "236", "237", "238", "239", "240", "241", "242", 
"243", "244", "246", "247", "248", "249", "250", "251", "252", 
"253", "254", "255", "256", "257", "258", "260", "261", "262", 
"263", "266", "267", "269", "270", "271", "272", "273", "274", 
"275", "276", "277", "278", "279", "280", "281", "282", "283", 
"284", "285", "286", "287", "288", "289", "290", "291", "292", 
"293", "294", "295", "296", "298", "299", "300"), class = "factor"), 
    age = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("high", "low"), class = "factor"), 
    time = structure(c(3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
    3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "4", "5"), class = "factor"), 
    dv = c(104, 102, 104, 103, 104, 104, 102, 102, 102, 102, 
    106, 106, 106, 106, 107, 107, 106, 106, 106, 107, 105, 104, 
    106, 107, 104, 101, 104, 101, 104, 106)), row.names = c(NA, 
-30L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Can you post the data, or a sample of the data? Check out how to use `dput()` in R; you can paste what that returns in something like gist.github.com. Regardless, what you're looking for can likely be done using `multcomp::glht()`

Comment: Thanks, I just added it.

Answer (score 5):

Load the `lme4` package, which fits multilevel models (an alternative to a repeated-measures ANOVA), and `emmeans`, which can do the contrasts.

```
library(lme4)
library(emmeans)
```

This fits a model where the `dv` is predicted by the interaction (R automatically fills-in the main effects), plus a random intercept and a random effect of `time`—both nested within `id`. `dat` is what I saved from the `dput` in your post.

```
mod <- lmer(dv ~ age * time + (1 + time | id), dat)
```

Contrasts are confusing, and I'm always paranoid I'm going to get it wrong. So we can use `emmeans` to find them. We can fit an `emmeans` object, which gets the values at each combination of `time` and `age`:

```
emm_mod <- emmeans(mod, ~ time + age)
```

The contrasts we want are the third and fourteenth from the `pairs()` result (run it on your own to see what it looks like). You can get the specific contrasts you want by putting `coef()` around the `pairs()` object. You just want the two columns—3rd and 14th:

```
(contr_mat <- coef(pairs(emm_mod))[, c("c.3", "c.14")])
```

Which returns:

```
       c.3 c.14
1,high   1    0
4,high   0    0
5,high   0    0
1,low   -1    1
4,low    0    0
5,low    0   -1
```

You can focus on these two contrasts by specifying them in `contr`. You can also use your p-value adjustment of choice by `adjust` to whatever—I'll start with `"holm"`:

```
emmeans(mod, ~ time + age, contr = contr_mat, adjust = "holm")
```

The `contrasts` bit will give you the p-values you are interested in:

```
$emmeans
 time age    emmean        SE df lower.CL upper.CL
 1    high 106.2500 0.6518719  3 104.1755 108.3245
 4    high 105.7500 0.8544406  3 103.0308 108.4692
 5    high 106.2500 0.4759431  3 104.7353 107.7647
 1    low  105.0000 0.5322511  3 103.3061 106.6939
 4    low  102.6667 0.6976478  3 100.4464 104.8869
 5    low  102.5000 0.3886059  3 101.2633 103.7367

Degrees-of-freedom method: kenward-roger 
Confidence level used: 0.95 

$contrasts
 contrast estimate        SE df t.ratio p.value
 c.3          1.25 0.8415630  3   1.485  0.2341
 c.14         2.50 0.7104068  3   3.519  0.0779

P value adjustment: holm method for 2 tests
```

You can also try `adjust = "none"`:

```
> emmeans(mod, ~ time + age, contr = contr_mat, adjust = "none")$contrasts
 contrast estimate        SE df t.ratio p.value
 c.3          1.25 0.8415630  3   1.485  0.2341
 c.14         2.50 0.7104068  3   3.519  0.0389
```

Comment: I found your answer extremely informative, and the procedure you describe is very useful to me in my own (mixed-effects model) project, which falls somewhere in between "nicely planned contrasts" and "post-hoc tests on all possible groups in the data" ... One question, though: Do you have any scientific references to the procedure you outline? I would really like to read more about this, but I haven't seen it treated anywhere (until now).